# How to loop through unnamed object with handlebars

Tags: node.js, templating, express-handlebars

I have the following object that is available under my /data get route:

```
{
  "_id": "5f1aa12b3abe8483ace9efc9",
  "email": "sales@inxy.com",
  "password": "124t42"
},
{
  "_id": "5f1ab53f0ef28b86ea1abdfd",
  "email": "a.zhukovski@gmail.com",
  "password": "2455"
}
]
```

I use handlebars templating engine and I fetch the data like this:
`fetch('/data').then(result => result.json()).then(data => data);`

I want to write out only emails to the page dynamically, so I want to use #each helper on handlebars template to achieve the task. However #each requires an argument, like this:

```
{{#each people}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
```

My JSON array is unnamed. I have tried to use '#each this' but I still cannot access anything in object.

What is the correct way of doing it?

Here is my backend code:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
const app = express();

// Create connection and connect to db
const addItem = (item) => {
  const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    const db = client.db('crudtest');
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Unable to connect to database', err);
    }
    console.log('Database connect success');
    try {
      db.collection('people').insertOne(item);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
}


//set views file
app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// set views engine
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// set public folder 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// home page route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('home');
})

app.get('/add-person', (req, res) => {
  res.render('addperson');
})

// route to fetch all data
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    const db = client.db('crudtest');
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Unable to connect to database', err);
    }
    try {
      const items = db.collection('people').find();
      if (items) {
        items.toArray().then((result) => res.send(result));
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  
  })
})

app.post('/add-person', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return console.log('Error!');
  }
  addItem(req.body);
  res.redirect('/');
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server has started');
})
```

home.handlebars -

```
<h1 class="mb-4 mt-4">From handlebars</h1>

{{#each result}}
  <div class="iterator"> {{ data.email }} </div>
{{/each }}
```

app.js

```
console.log('From client side JS');
fetch('/data').then(result => result.json()).then(data => { data });
```

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: No errors, I just don't know what to put as an argument to #each ```{{#each this}}
  <div class="iterator"> {{ this.email }} </div>
{{/each }}```  I use the following syntax and it just gives me 3 empty divs

Comment: It isn't clear how you pass the data to the handlebars. Can you add the code? If the `data` is an array and it is what you pass to the handlebars then you could try `.json()).then(data => { people: data} );` then `{{#each people}}` should work.

Comment: I use main.handlebars layout. it looks like this:
```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <title>Test CRUD</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{{body}}}
  <script src="/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>```

Comment: in /js/app.js I have the following
```
fetch('/data').then(result => result.json()).then(data => data);
```

Comment: @Molda I have tried modifying request to ```fetch('/data').then(result => result.json()).then(data => { people : data })``` but it even doesn't give me empty divs if I use #each people;

Comment: Is that all the code you have in /js/app.js? The fetch function doesn't pass any data anywhere. Either there's more code around the fetch or you are actualy rendering the html on the server and the code in /js/app.js is not the code that creates the divs. Show me the server-side code for the route where you get this html. **Add it to your question, don't post it as a comment!**

Comment: Sure, @Molda, thank you for your feedback, I have updated my question accordingly. Seems like I miss something since I thought that fetch brings the data into handlebars since I have app.js in main.handlebars template

Comment: Ok, it's clear now that the fetch in the /js/app.js doesn't do anything. You can delete that. Also the fetch in `app.get('/'...` is nonsence. All you need to do is to move the code from `app.get('/data'` to `app.get('/'` and instead of calling `res.send(result)` call `res.render('home', { people: data })` then finaly the `#each people` should work.

Comment: Also if you thought that this `fetch('/data').then(result => result.json()).then(data => data)` was doing something then i would strongly recommend you to start by learning the basics of javascript.

Comment: This have worked perfectly, thanks a lot, @Molda. As far as I understand I don't need a separate /data route in this case? Would I need it in future for anything CRUD-related?

Comment: @Molda, actually I have messed my index.js accidentally and there shouldn't have been any fetch inside '/' route. Thanks again for pointing to this.

Comment: In real application you gonna need a lot of routes for different purposes. Some for rendering views, some API routes to serve data only and some routes for uploads and so on. I§m glad i works for you now.

Comment: @Molda, thanks again for help. Much appreciated.